# Get unique set of pairs of ObjectIds using MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

So I'm at some stage in the aggregation pipeline and my documents currently look like this:

```
{
    { a: 'ObjectIDA', b: 'ObjectIDB' },
    { a: 'ObjectIDB', b: 'ObjectIDA' },
    { a: 'ObjectIDC', b: 'ObjectIDB' },
    { a: 'ObjectIDA', b: 'ObjectIDC' },
    ...
}
```

How do I filter these documents to only get unique pairs of ObjectIds?

Answer (score 1):

If by "unique pair" you mean only "ObjectA" and "ObjectB" in any order then you need to do something like:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
       "combined": {
           "$map": {
               "input": { "$literal": ["A","B"] },
               "as": "i",
               "in": { "$cond": [
                   { "$eq": [ "$$i", "A" ] },
                   "$a",
                   "$b"
               ]}
           }
       }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$combined" },
    { "$sort": { "_id": 1, "combined": 1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "combined": { "$push": "$combined" }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$combined"
    }}
])
```

Which produces:

```js
{ "_id" : [ "ObjectIDA", "ObjectIDB" ] }
{ "_id" : [ "ObjectIDB", "ObjectIDC" ] }
{ "_id" : [ "ObjectIDA", "ObjectIDC" ] }
```

So the key points there are:

1. Get the elements into an array
2. Sort the arrary to be in consistent order
3. Group on the consistently ordered arrays

That uses operators introduced with MongoDB 2.6, but you can do the same with earlier versions:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 1,
        "type": { "$const": [ "A", "B" ] }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$type" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "combined": {
            "$push": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$type", "A" ] },
                    "$a",
                    "$b"
                ]
            }
        }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$combined" },
    { "$sort": { "_id": 1, "combined": 1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "combined": { "$push": "$combined" }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$combined"
    }}
])
```

---

Open up a shell and insert the information exactly as "you" presented it:

```js
db.collection.drop();
db.collection.insert([
    { a: 'ObjectIDA', b: 'ObjectIDB' },
    { a: 'ObjectIDB', b: 'ObjectIDA' },
    { a: 'ObjectIDC', b: 'ObjectIDB' },
    { a: 'ObjectIDA', b: 'ObjectIDC' }
]);
```

Now run the aggregation statement "exactly" as I present it, and see the same results I posted before:

```js
{ "_id" : [ "ObjectIDA", "ObjectIDB" ] }
{ "_id" : [ "ObjectIDB", "ObjectIDC" ] }
{ "_id" : [ "ObjectIDA", "ObjectIDC" ] }
```

Which removes the duplicate occurance of "ObjectIDA" and "ObjectIDB" in reverse order.

The consistent ordering is what this is all about.